# Relationship between an Exponential and Geometric RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Take $Y \sim \exp(\beta).$ Take $X = k$ if $k-1 \leq Y < k$ for
$k \in \mathbb{N}.$ I want to show that $X$ has a geometric distribution, and I
want to figure out the parameterization of that distribution.

I imagine that the first thing to do is to solve for some arbitrary $k \in
\mathbb{N},$ $P(X = k).$ We know that
$$P(X = k) = P(k-1 \leq Y < k) = P(Y \leq k) - P(Y \leq k-1)$$
by the properties of a continuous CDF. This seems to me to be
$$= \int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{\beta} e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} x} dx
= \frac{1}{\beta} \int_{k-1}^k e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} x} dx.$$
If we perform a $u$-substitution by setting $u = -\frac{x}{\beta}
\implies du = -\frac{dx}{\beta}$, this suggests that our above equation is
$$= - \int e^u = - (e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}} \mid_{k-1}^k) =
e^{-\frac{k-1}{\beta}} - e^{-\frac{k}{\beta}}.$$
However, I am seeming to have some issues getting this in the form of a
geometric distribution. Any recommendations?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Only thing that confuses me is $X\sim \exp(\beta)$. This usually means that the PDF of $X$ is $\beta e^{-\beta x} 1_{[0,\infty)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$P(X = k) = e^{-\frac{k-1}{\beta}} - e^{-\frac{k}{\beta}}$$

This can be rewritten as: $$P(X = k) = e^{-\frac{k-1}{\beta}} - e^{-\frac{k-1}{\beta}}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}= (1-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}})e^{-\frac{k-1}{\beta}}= (1-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}) \left (e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}\right )^{k-1}$$

I think you need to take note of the other comment made and see if you can make some changes...